# How to use loop and if condition of output of command

Tags: python, bash, shell

I using a command to get desired output

```
geek@geek:~/test$   ./mycommand --server 192.168.0.1:8080 --describe --group mygroup

TOPIC              PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                    HOST            CLIENT-ID
my-group            7          812             812             0               asdfghjk-1234faf5-5678-4a6f-8f09-bfa363f49984 /192.168.0.11   asdfghjk
my-group            6          719             719             0               asdfghjk-1234faf5-5678-4a6f-8f09-bfa363f49984 /192.168.0.11   asdfghjk
my-group            2          785             785             0               asdfghjk-1234faf5-5678-4a6f-8f09-bfa363f49984 /192.168.0.11   asdfghjk
my-group            0          752             752             0               asdfghjk-1234faf5-5678-4a6f-8f09-bfa363f49984 /192.168.0.11   asdfghjk
```

I am sorting it with awk like below

```
geek@geek:~/test$   ./mycommand --server 192.168.0.1:8080 --describe --group mygroup|  awk '{print $5}'
LAG
0
0
0
0
```

Now i want to print whole line if that value goes from `0` to beyond `1000`.
How do I achieve it?

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in form of code. Could you please explain more about your expected output and explain logic of how to get it too in your question.

Comment: At present value show `0`. I want to get whole line of which value goes beyond `1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk statement should do what you wnated :

```
awk '{if ( ($5 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) && $5 > 1000) { print } else { print $5 } }'
```